# How to add an array of elements in order?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array: `const arr = [1, 2, 5, 10]`;

How I can transform it to `const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`?;

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Having any issues? Would an input of `[1, 10]` or `[1, 3, 10]` have the same output as your expected `[1, 2..., 10]`?

Comment: Do you need to store in the same variable?

Comment: @HirenPatel Not necessary. I just need to fill the array.

Comment: means you can store in another variable then you can use the answer given by @Adriani6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 10];

for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) { // Loop from 1 till 10, including 10
    if (!arr.includes(i)) { // If arr does not include 'i'
        arr.splice(i - 1, 0, i); // We insert it into the array
        // -1, because arrays start at 0
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way to do it without hard-coding the number of iterations is to get the minimum value from the array and the maximum and then fill the numbers in-between them.

Here's one way to do it

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 10];

var highest = Math.max(...arr);
var minimum = Math.min(...arr);

var output = [];

for(var i = minimum; i <= highest; i++){
 output.push(i);
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: For better browser support (e.g. IE, all versions) `apply` could be used instead of the spread operator. E.g. `Math.min.apply(null, arr)` and `Math.max.apply(null, arr)`.
See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner solution based on  Adriani6 answer:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 5, 10];

var highest = Math.max(...arr);
var minimum = Math.min(...arr);

const newArr = ([...Array(highest+1).keys()]).slice(minimum);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a nested `while` statement and splice missing items.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 5, 10],
    i = array.length;

while (i--) while (array[i - 1] + 1 < array[i]) array.splice(i, 0, array[i] - 1);

console.log(...array);
```